# Where does "journalctl" read configurations from?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, configuration, systemctl, kubernetes

I have installed `kubelet 1.26.0` on my `Ubuntu 22.04` machine. Previously I had `1.25.2` version that I removed by `apt remove kubelet` command and reinstalled it with `apt install kubelet` command. Wherever I search for `kubelet`'s configuration and look at it, it shows the `1.26.0` version, but when I run `journalctl -xu kubelet.service` it shows the following result:

```
Dec 06 22:14:42 a systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 11743.
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.254559   85576 server.go:413] "Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.25.4"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.254699   85576 server.go:415] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.255385   85576 server.go:576] "Standalone mode, no API client"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.295733   85576 server.go:464] "No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.295813   85576 server.go:660] "--cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: E1206 22:14:43.296299   85576 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swa>
Dec 06 22:14:43 a systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
Dec 06 22:14:43 a systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit kubelet.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
```

It shows that the `"Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.25.4"` and I am also suspect if the configuration is not as I expected and because of that the `kubelet` doesn't work properly. But I don't know where does this wrong configuration come from and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`journalctl -xu kubelet.service` shows *all* the recorded logs from the `kubelet.service` that are currently stored on your system. Removing a service will not automatically remove the log entries it has generated.

Note that the messages you are viewing are dated December 6; if you had not yet installed kubelet 1.26.0 at that date, those messages were generated by the older version and have not yet expired from the system journal. If you installed the newer `kubelet` version at sometime after December 6, you should see a newer version once you move forward in the journal, past the time you did the reinstallation.

Press SPACE or use the down arrow key within `journalctl` to view more recent logs, or use `journalctl -xeu kubelet.service` to immediately jump to the most recent logs at the end of the listing.

---

`journalctl` reads its configuration from `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, but that won't help you much, as it only deals mainly with the storage of the journal, expiration of the log entries and forwarding of the log messages to other logging services (if configured). It normally has no settings in it that are specific to an individual service like `kubelet.service`.

If you want to see exactly how the `kubelet.service` is defined, you should use `systemctl cat kubelet.service` instead. The advantage of this command is, it will always list the *complete* service definition as `systemd` sees it, no matter where the service definition file is located or if any override files have been applied on top of it.

---

Also, note this message:

```
"command failed" err="failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swa>
```

Kubelet 1.25.2 apparently failed because you had swap enabled on your system.

I would expect Kubelet 1.26.0 to also fail with the same issue unless you also disabled swap at some point between December 6 and now, or added the

```
failSwapOn: false
```

setting to the configuration of the kubelet node, or added the option recommended in the *complete* error message into the `ExecStart` line(s) of `kubelet.service`.

---

The `>` at the end of the message above indicates the message is longer than your terminal could fit, and you would have seen the rest of the message by using the right-arrow key within `journalctl`. This also makes it harder to copy long journal messages from `journalctl` output, which is annoying in my opinion.

If you (like me) don't like this `journalctl` behavior, you might want to set an environment variable

```
export SYSTEMD_LESS=FRXMK
```

to allow long lines to wrap (to allow easy copy/paste of **complete** log messages) instead of requiring right/left scrolling to see the whole of a long journal message.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete answer! Yes I think one of the problems could be the `swap` that I tried a lot to shut it down but I couldn't! I tried `sudo swapoff -a`, I tried to add `Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false` for `ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS` within the `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Also I did comment out `#UUID=f49e3ded-109a-45cf-82ff-d9810a32546a none            swap    sw              0       0` line inside `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: After commenting out swap from  `/etc/fstab`, you might need to update your initramfs, with `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: I ran your last suggested command but I still get `E1212 08:01:39.933506  291449 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused` errors when I try `kubectl get pods` and other commands.